# float precision with Numba

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I'm currently using Numba to speed up calculations, and so far it's going pretty well. I've run into small issue. `print('{B:.4f}'.format(B))` Numba does not support f strings or format. I'm wondering if anyone has been able to work around this? Is there a Numpy function that changes the precision, or changing all float values to float 32bit, or would it be easier to create a function that changes the precision of the float?

I am using `@njit`, and I understand that `@jit` defaults to object mode, but `@njit` significantly decreases run time in my case, which is what my goal is.

Comment: Don't you mean `'{0:.4f}'.format(B)`?

Comment: @JérômeRichard yes, sorry about that. The issue is still the same though.

Comment: It appear there is surprisingly  no support for float to string conversion in Numba yet. In fact string are barely supported so far and there is no (short-term) plan to work on them. Even `str(B)` or `np.format_float_positional` are unfortunately not supported yet. You can ask for the feature to be implemented on the Github project since it is quite important to have a minimal support for string conversion. However, I am not sure `format` will be implemented soon since implementing such a function in nopython mode is probably not easy (as opposed to `str`).